# http.NewRequest(DELETE) to Tanium REST-API returns error with different body than the one added to the request

Tags: rest, go, httprequest

I am working with the Tanium REST-API and I'm trying to delete a suppression rule. The documentation states that the `body` needs to be as follows:

[image: Excerpt from official Tanium Documentation concerning Suppression Rule Deletion]

Below is the code I'm using:

```golang
func (t *TaniumClient) deleteSuppressionRules(ruleId []int) error {
    //TODO: Fix this messy code
    url := t.BaseUrl + "/plugin/products/threat-response/api/v1/suppression-rules/bulk/delete"
    var selectedIDs, selected []int
    var selection string

    if len(ruleId) != 0 {
        for _, rID := range ruleId {
            selectedIDs = append(selectedIDs, rID)
        }
        selection = "include"
        selected = selectedIDs
    } else {
        selectedIDs = append(selectedIDs, 9999)
        selection = "exclude"
        selected = selectedIDs
    }

    delBody := deleteRequestBody{
        SelectionMode: selection,
        Selected: selected
    }

    marshalled, err := json.Marshal(delBody)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    req, err := http.NewRequest("DELETE", url, bytes.NewBuffer(marshalled))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    req.Header.Add("session", t.SessionToken)
    req.Header.Add("User-Agent", userAgent)

    if _, err := t.doRequest(req); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

type deleteRequestBody struct {
    SelectionMode string                `json:"selectionMode"`
    Filters       []deleteRequestFilter `json:"filters,omitempty"`
    Selected      []int                 `json:"selected"`
}

func (t *TaniumClient) doRequest(req *http.Request) ([]byte, error) {
    req.Header.Add("session", t.SessionToken)
    req.Header.Add("User-Agent", userAgent)

    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if !(resp.StatusCode >= 200 && resp.StatusCode < 300) {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("%s", body)
    }
    return body, nil
}
```

But I always get an error message indicating that my `body` is not correct:

```json
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "BadRequest",
            "description": "\"value\" must contain at least one of [selected, filters]",
            "details": [
                {
                    "message": "\"value\" must contain at least one of [selected, filters]",
                    "path": [],
                    "type": "object.missing",
                    "context": {
                        "peers": [
                            "selected",
                            "filters"
                        ],
                        "peersWithLabels": [
                            "selected",
                            "filters"
                        ],
                        "label": "value",
                        "value": {
                            "selectionMode": "include"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Despite the error message, the JSON that is being sent with the DELETE request actually includes the `selection` property.

If I access the same API-endpoint via Python, it works with no issues:

```py
def deleteSuppressionRules(self, selected_ids:[int] = []) -> str:
    url = t.BaseUrl + "/plugin/products/threat-response/api/v1/suppression-rules/bulk/delete"

    if len(selected_ids) < 1:
        payload = {
            "selectionMode": "exclude",
            "selected": [
                9999
            ]
        }
    else:
        payload = {
            "selectionMode": "include",
            "selected": selected_ids
        }

    headers = {"session": self.sessionToken}

    response = requests.request("DELETE", url, json=payload,
                                headers=headers, verify=False)
```

Am I doing something wrong, overlooking an obvious mistake - maybe I'm just stupid - or is there an actual bug in the Tanium API?

Comment: The code can be improved. But there is not obvious mistake in the current code. How `t.doRequest` is implemented? Have you tried to send the request with `cURL` to check if the server works correctly?

Comment: @ZekeLu - If I run the same request via Python, it works, so I suppose the server works correctly (I have added the `doRequest` function and the python-code to the question, thanks).

Comment: Try setting the `Content-Type` header with the value `application/json`. If it still does not work, dump the request from both Go and python to see if there is any difference.

Comment: Well, I'm just gonna drown myself, thanks a lot for the help - it works now (－‸ლ)